# How to plot a dashed line on pine script V4?

Tags: pine-script

Trying to plot a normal serie line but with the V4 of pine script I can't find how to set the style?

This gives me an error :

`plot(my_serie, color=color.blue,linewidth=2, style=line.style_dashed)`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no dashed style for `plot()`. This turns the color on and off to achieve the effect:

```
plot(my_serie, color=bar_index % 2 == 0 ? color.blue : #00000000, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: This works. But the dash line drawn this way doesn't look like the original hline dashed line unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for this precious information. You are absolutely right. Our apologies; we should of course have warned potential users that this is a workaround which they should stay away from if they require precisely the same look as that produced by `hline`, which doesn't plot series.

Comment: In the latest version of Pine (v4), use  `n` instead of `bar_index`:
`color=n % 2 == 0 ? blue : #00000000`

Comment: That's incorrect. In Pine v1 to v3, `n` was the equivalent of what is now `bar_index` in v4.

Answer (score -4):

Use the below -

Change the end part based on your requirement, set

`style=plot.style_dashed`

Comment: This enum doesnt exist

Comment: `plot()` does not have this property but `line()` has.