# How to display/hide a hline using input from user?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to allow users of my script to display or hide some dashed horizontal lines.

I can't find the way to do this using hline.

I've managed to do it using plot, but there is no dashed line format for plot.
(I know there is a trick to plot dash lines: [How to plot a dashed line on pine script V4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854071/how-to-plot-a-dashed-line-on-pine-script-v4), but the end result doesn't look like the original hline dash line.)

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("")
showHline = input(true)
hline(50, color = showHline ? color.blue : #00000000)
plot(na)
```

Comment: And now I would like to add a condition for the display of hline.
I've tried this
`code` Cond = Value>100
hline (100, color = Cond ? #A62A4E : #00000000)`code`

But it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You already have a condition in the supplied code, which you select through the script's Settings/Inputs. An hline cannot be turned on for some bars and off for others, like a `plot()` can.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the transparency of the color to 100 based on your conditions to show/hide the line

```
transparency = condition ? 100 : 0
yourLine = hline(50, "Zero",color=color.new(color.black, transparency))
```

define `condition` to derive `transparency` as per your requirements