# Adding Transparency to Hline display/hide function

Tags: pine-script

How do you add color transparency to an optional showing hline in pinescript? I have followed the  guide on how to add show/hide optionality into the script by the help of  [How to display/hide a hline using input from user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859355/how-to-display-hide-a-hline-using-input-from-user/64093083#64093083), however adding transparency to hline color additionaly has resulted in errors.

This is the optionality line of the code, however succesfully adding the complimentary transparency color part to has proven unsuccessful by my strife:

```
showHline = input(false)
hline(0, color = showHline ? color.orange : #000000)
```

Comments: The #000000 at the very end can be arbitrary figures and it does not affect the color

Comment: Ways which do not work: 
   hline1=hline(200)
   plot(hline1, color=color.red, transp=50)

Answer (score 2):

You can add transparency to a color with the color.new() function:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
col1 = color.new(color.red, 80)
l1 = hline(1, color=col1)
plot(na)
```

Comment: Yes, the new color function in pinescript v4 has been refined, however this line of code does not work when trying to compliment transparency with the "Show Hline?" optionality, hence does not solve the issue unfortunately.
This is the code for adding optionality to the hline, with various color functions, but without the ability to add transparency as far as I know of.
   showHline = input(false)
   hline(0, color = showHline ? color.orange : #000000)

Comment: I think I've figured a solution to my issue. Will return with code soon.